# How to protect a route with middleware in laravel?

Tags: laravel, authentication, middleware

i have a problem with my middleware. when i login as admin, it's working fine and redirect to `/Admin/home` same as Operator (i have 2 user, Admin & Operator). The problem is when i hit url as example : `/Operator/home` as Admin role, it can access it. And that's the problem.

I'have create a new middleware `CheckMiddleware`, and registered to kernel in array $routeMiddleware as checkMiddleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = $request->user();

        if ($user) {
            if ($user->isAdmin()) {
                return $next($request);
            }elseif($user->isOperator()){
                return $next($request);
            }
        }

        return dd('Forbidden page. you have to login as admin/operator');
    }
```

In the route :

```
Route::group(['prefix'=>'Admin' ,'middleware' => 'checkMiddleware'], function() {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('homeAdmin');
});

Route::group(['prefix'=>'Operator' ,'middleware' => 'checkMiddleware'], function() {
    Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('homeAdmin');
});

Auth::routes();
```

in User model :

```
public function isAdmin(){
        if ($this->role_id === 1) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public  function isOperator(){
        if ($this->role_id === 2) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

What i want is, Admin cannot access Operator and Operator Cannot Access Admin. 
if this is not clear, tell me what file you want to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is if `user` is `admin` then accept request and `user` is `operator` still accept request. That code below

```
if ($user->isAdmin()) {
    return $next($request);
}elseif($user->isOperator()){
    return $next($request);
}
```

For simple solution, just create two middleware for admin and operator. Then apply `admin` middleware for route (group) need `admin` role, and apply `operator` middleware for route (group) need `operator` role.

If you have some route allow `admin` and `operator` role access, just add both to that route.

**UPDATE**
If you want to use 1 middleware, do like this :

```
if ($user->isAdmin() && $request->route()->getPrefix() == 'admin') {
    return $next($request);
}
if ($user->isOperator() && $request->route()->getPrefix() == 'operator') {
    return $next($request);
}
return abort(401) // OR SOME ROUTE YOU WANT
```

Comment: thx for the response. it works like a charm. but can it be in 1 middleware?